# Cannot open the connection for the driver: org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc

Tags: eclipse, birt

I got the following problem

In Eclipse, in the Report Design Perspective , when I try to preview I get the following error:

```
Chart NewChart: 
+ An exception occurred during processing. Please see the following message for details:
Cannot open the connection for the driver: org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.
    org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.JDBCException: Cannot load JDBC Driver class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver.
```

I also checked in Eclipse in the folder org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc/drivers and it was empty. Should it be?
I checked the externalLibs directory, and there I have mysql-connector.jar and I do not know what to check for next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JDBC driver must be copied to that directory, see also http://www.eclipse.org/birt/phoenix/deploy/viewerSetup.php#install_jdbc

Comment: So... i can not view the report neither in eclipse, nor in jboss. 
I copied the mysql-connector-java-5.1.11-bin.jar to
for eclipse - eclipse\eclipse 3.5.2 RCP+JEE\plugins\org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc_2.5.2.v20100205\drivers 
and eclipse\eclipse 3.5.2 RCP+JEE\plugins\org.eclipse.birt.report.viewer_2.5.2.v20091210\birt\WEB-INF\plugins\org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc_2.5.2.v20100205\drivers
and for jboss deploy\birt.war\WEB-INF\platform\plugins\org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc_2.6.1.v20100909\drivers

Comment: for eclipse

- An exception occurred during processing. Please see the following message for details:
Cannot open the connection for the driver: org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.
    org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.JDBCException: Cannot load JDBC Driver class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver.

for jboss

-  for  jboss  
 List (id = 997): 
- Can not load the report query: 997. Errors occurred when generating the report document for the report element with ID 997.

Comment: Open your DataSource by double-click in the BIRT Designer and click on the "Manage Drivers..." Button. There are listed the drivers found in the drivers directory. Please check if the MySQL driver is present in that view, otherwise add the driver and check if the report is running properly in the BIRT designer

Answer (score 4):

Do one thing MARA, go to the **Data Source** option. Select **JDBC Connection** over there do `Next`. You will find an <kbd>Manage Drivers</kbd> button in the left-bottom of the window. Select it, a new console window named **Manage JDBC Drivers** will evolve. There you will find two tabs Jar Files and Driver. Now select Jar Files and add a newly created `.jar` file (know how to create a .jar file it's quite easy, google it). Click <kbd>Ok</kbd>. You are done.

Now whenever you will go the data source and select **Driver Class** = `com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver`.(Or you may see its turned to `com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver(com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver (v4.0) v4.0)`) just write the connection string on the **Base url**. (Don't forget to open a port from the server side you are using).

Hope it works.

Comment: it took me a minute to realize MARA is the OP. :D

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

Download **mysql-connector-java-5.1.44-bin.jar** file from google

Paste the jar file to location: *Eclipse⁩/⁨Contents⁩/⁨Eclipse⁩/⁨plugins⁩/org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc_*.../drivers⁩* **folder**

or

paste "mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar" jar file to

location: *WEB-INF\platform\plugins\org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc_INSTALLED_VERSION\drivers* **folder**

Go to **manage drivers**, under **jar files** section use **add** option and select the **mysql-connector-java-5.1.44-bin.jar** file from any location from your local machine and then **Test Connection**

**Connection Successful**